# Building a Huffman Tree in C. The result is always only a tree with the root and its two sons

Tags: pointers, huffman-code

I've been trying to build a Huffman tree in C with this algorithm.

```
struct node *temp1, *temp2, *new_node;
while (size != 1) {
      temp1 = extractmin(minheap, size);
      size--;
      temp2 = extractmin(minheap, size);
      size--;
      new_node = newnode((temp1->frequency) + (temp2->frequency), '$');
      new_node->lson = temp1;
      new_node->rson = temp2;
      insert(minheap, new_node, size);
      size++;
}
struct node * extractmin(struct node * heap[], int N) {
    struct node *min = heap[1];
    struct node *temp = newnode((heap[N])->frequency, (heap[N])->c);
    heap[1] = temp;
    N = N - 1;
    min_heapify(heap, 1, N);
    return min;
}
void insert(struct node * heap[], struct node * new_node, int N) {
    int i, j;
    N = N + 1;
    i = N;
    j = (i / 2);
    while ((i > 1) && ((heap[j])->frequency > (new_node)->frequency)) {
            heap[i] = heap[j];
            i = j;
            j = i / 2;
    }  
    heap[i] = new_node;
}
```

The result always seems to be a tree only with its root and its two sons. Trying to access a son of any of its sons always returns NULL and causes Segementation faults. What am I doing that results to that?

Comment: What is the definition of `struct node`? What is the definition of `newnode()`? `minheapify()`?

Comment: And why are you indexing with `[1]` and `[N]`? Those should probably be `[0]` and `[N-1]`.